# MySQL CREATE TRIGGER, Syntax Error. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, concatenation

```
 DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER `monthly_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `history_monthly`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    NEW.`uid` = CONCAT(OLD.`year`, OLD.`month`, OLD.`charactersId`);
END;
||
DELIMITER ;
```

And it returns an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`uid` = CONCAT(OLD.`year`, OLD.`month`, OLD.`charactersId`);
END' at line 4
```

It's my first time with triggers and I was doing my best to try to find soultion but I failed ;<

Comment: If this is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, surely there won't be an old row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the word `SET` in this line:

```
SET NEW.`uid` = CONCAT(OLD.`year`, OLD.`month`, OLD.`charactersId`);
```

Also, as the commenter pointed out, there is no `OLD` value in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.